# Android: как можно программно поменять layout-width у ImageView?

Tags: android, java

Android: как можно программно поменять layout-width у ImageView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = imageView.getLayoutParams();
// если специфические свойства, то брать LayoutParams у конкретного класса layout

params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; // или числом
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```